What does this "an approach to such a thing" mean here?
In A School Story, by M. R. James, the listener had asked the narrator here to tell a ghost story connected with a school, then the narrator told him a long story, concluding it in this way.

“That is my story,” said the narrator.
“The only approach to a ghost story connected with a school that I know, but still, I think, an approach to such a thing.”

What does "but still, I think, an approach to such a thing" mean?

One of Oxford's definitions of approach as a noun is an approximation to something. The narrator seems to mean "This is the nearest thing I know to a ghost story set in a school."

@KateBunting But he already said "The only approach to a ghost story connected with a school that I know", so why did he add "but still, I think, an approach to such a thing"?

I don't know. "This is the only example I know, but it's something like a ghost story." But this is more about literary interpretation than English.

Paraphrase: It is the only ghost story about a school that I know and, even though I don't have another ghost story about a school to compare it to, I think it is a decent attempt.

For my American English ear, the passage could be paraphrased as but I do think that its way of attempting to achieve the task (of creating a ghost story connected with a school) is a reasonable one.
